# OAuth Redirect URI login on custom web app via native facebook app

Tags: facebook, authentication, web-applications, oauth

I have facebook authentication on my web app and work perfectly. But when I'm not logged in on the browser I want to detect facebook native app and login via this app.
Do you know what Valid OAuth redirect URIs I should have?

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a custom redirect scheme which invokes the app from the system. Look at creating custom redirect uri schemes here and invoke your app from using this. For example if you define `redirect_uri=myapp.facebook.com` you can register the same on your system whcih calls facebook.exe/facebook.sh.

**Creating Custom schemes**

Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
Linux:http://edoceo.com/howto/xfce-custom-uri-handler